# output error in printing string in python

Tags: python

to print the whole name but only single name is printing.

```
name = input(raw_input())
print  ('Hello', name,'! You just delved into python.')
```

Input

```
Ross
Taylor
```

Output

```
Ross
```

Expected Output

```
Hello Ross Taylor! You just delved into python.
```

Comment: Try `print  ('Hello ' + name + '! You just delved into python.')`

Comment: How did you input multiple lines, exactly?

Comment: How are you giving that input?

Comment: not working I have tried that one. I need like the input I have shown so that the output will ci=ome in single line

Comment: The input should be like that as it is given and output will be in a single sentence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do

```
name = input(raw_input())
```

You can either do

```
name = input()
```

or

```
name = raw_input()
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter key or the newline is key for ending input to raw_input function. So either you write whole name in a single line as @Andreau suggested or you need to use some other method. There is python package called [Getch](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/getch), that might help you in this regard.

Answer (score -1):

```py
def print_full_name(a, b):
    print("Hello", a, b + "!", "You just delved into python.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    first_name = input()
    last_name = input()
    print_full_name(first_name, last_name)
```

You will get the output while executing this program.